# How to exclude non selected fields and print out the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a form that has 5 fields, namely

```
sale_date
product_id
product_name
price
number_of_units
```

These are all check boxes and the user can select any of the fields.

By using the below for loop I am able to print out the list of columns selected.

```
    for fieldname, value in form.data.items():
        print(fieldname,value)
```

How could I modify the above **for loop** such that it prints only selected fields such that *None* (which should return when the field is not selected) are excluded.

Thanks

Comment: `if value is not None: print(fieldname,value)`? With the print statement on a new line obviously.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Can you include some context. Where is this loop? After `form.is_valid()` ?

Comment: @daniherrera, I am trying to print out all the selected fields from a form (Excluding the columns that are not selected).

Comment: @Loocid, thanks that helped..

Comment: @Loocid is there a way we could covert the output of the print statement to a list.